# Another SQL tutorial question: Field > 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Alright, [this one](http://sqlzoo.net/1a.htm) (3a; sample problem with provided answer) has got me scratching my head:

> **bbc(name, region, area, population, gdp)**
>   *3a. Find the largest country in each region:*

```
SELECT region, name, population
  FROM bbc x
 WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population
       FROM bbc y
      WHERE y.region = x.region
        AND population > 0)
```

I understand the concept of '`WHERE y.region = x.region`' when I think about it in terms of the db engine looping over the table entries and matching each x.region with the current y.region (in the nested SELECT)... but wtf does '`AND population > 0`' do?  It isn't a right answer without it, but I don't see how not...

Comment: nit pick: your question asks for the largest country (intuitively that is the area), yet the sample SELECT goes looking for the most populous. You might want to rephrase the question.

Comment: It's a copypasta.  That's how they wrote it.  I agree, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That clause is there just because there is an entry in the Europe table (for the Vatican) which has NULL in the population column.  The following works also and I believe is more understandable:

```
SELECT region, name, population
  FROM bbc x
 WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population
       FROM bbc y
      WHERE y.region = x.region
        AND population IS NOT NULL)
```

In the [MySQL documentation for ALL subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html), there's a helpful comment (emphasis theirs):

> In general, *tables containing **NULL** values* and *empty tables* are "edge cases." When writing subquery code, always consider whether you have taken those two possibilities into account.

Answer (score 2):

I am speculating it here.

What if population is null for all of the records of a specific region?

EDIT: It can be considered kind of a safety-net to ignore -ve values in population (not a real life scenario).

Comment: I don't recall it specifying that it was.  And I haven't even started to cover the null stuff with that tutorial, yet.

Comment: Negative values would not be a problem.